# openssl create csr template error "No template, please set one up."

Tags: openssl, aws

I'm attempting to create a csr on an Amazon Linux AMI 2017.03.0 image.
I run the following command to generate the test.key

```
[root]# openssl genrsa -out test.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
............+++
.........................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
[root]#
```

I then run the following:

```
[root]# openssl req -new -sha256 -key test.key -out test.csr
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
No template, please set one up.
problems making Certificate Request
[root]#
```

The "No template, please set one up" appear to relate to the openssl.conf file

My openssl config is as follows:

```
[root]# pwd
/etc/ssl
[root]# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr  3 22:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 82 root root 4096 Apr 21 10:54 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Jan 20 23:25 certs -> ../pki/tls/certs
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  138 Apr  3 22:53 openssl.cnf
[root]# cat openssl.cnf
[ ssl_client ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
[root]# rpm -q -a |grep openssl
openssl-1.0.1k-15.99.amzn1.x86_64
[root]#
```

Doesn't appear to be a great deal of info about creating openssl templates, can anyone help or give me a link to examples or tutorial.

Comment: What you have in the ssl_client stanza will not apply when making csr. Those are actually x509v3 extended attributes normally added to the certificate by CA when signing the CSR and they are referenced as `openssl x509 ... -extensions ssl_client`. If you need to fill the subject field, you must use `openssl req -new -sha256 -key test.key -out test.csr -subj "/C=SM/ST=somecountry/L=someloc/O=someorg/OU=somedept/CN=example.com"` or whatever you need.

Comment: @Fiisch You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Already done. Previously, I was in a bit of a hurry for a proper answer, so I just wrote a comment. :)

Answer (score 4):

What you have in the ssl_client stanza will not apply when making csr. Those are actually x509v3 extended attributes normally added to the certificate by CA when signing the CSR and they are referenced by the stanza name:

```
openssl x509 ... -extensions ssl_client
```

If you need to fill the subject field, you must use something like:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -key test.key -out test.csr -subj "/C=SM/ST=somecountry/L=someloc/O=someorg/OU=somedept/CN=exa‌​mple.com"
```

There are also ways to specify defaults through `req` and `req_distinguished_name` stanza. By specifying in the `req`, you configure defaults for the `openssl req ...` command. By specifying `req_distinguished_name` you can set limitations on the subject DN components and also set defaults for the interactive CSR creation you usually invoke with `openssl req -new ...` and such.

The defaults can be set as follows:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName_default             = SM
stateOrProvinceName_default     = somecountry
localityName_default            = someloc
...
```

There are two awesome pages I usually refer to when I want to do something with commandline openssl:

https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/appendix/root-configuration-file.html

https://www.phildev.net/ssl/opensslconf.html

Comment: Thanks, I used the sample config file from your first link for `easyrsa build-ca` in a custom new `pki` folder, I saved it as `pki/openssl-easyrsa.cnf`. From this it generated the `pki/safessl-easyrsa.cnf`file, and then generated the CA certificate. Without this sample config, I was receiving errors such as **No template, please set one up.
problems making Certificate Request** , but with this sample config it worked perfectly.